# Python Pandas - Day and Month mix up

Tags: python, date, pandas

I have a 'myfile.csv' file which has a 'timestamp' column which starts at

(01/05/2015  11:51:00)

and finishes at

(07/05/2015  23:22:00)

A total span of 9,727 minutes

'myfile.csv' also has a column named 'A' which is some numerical value, there are values are multiple values for 'A' within each minute, each with a  unique timestamp to the nearest second.

I have code as follows

```
df = pd.read_csv('myfile.csv')
df = df.set_index('timestamp')
df.index = df.index.to_datetime()
df.sort_index(inplace=True)
df = df['A'].resample('1Min').mean()
df.index = (df.index.map(lambda t: t.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')))
```

My problem is that python seems to think 'timestamp' starts at

(01/05/2015  11:51:00)

-> 5th January

and finishes at

(07/05/2015  23:22:00)

-> 5th July

But really 'timestamp' starts at the

1st May

and finishes at the

7th of May

So the above code produces a dataframe with 261,332 rows, OMG, when it should really only have 9,727 rows.

Somehow Python is mixing up the month with the day, misinterpreting the dates, how do I sort this out?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are many arguments within `csv_read` that can help you parse dates from a csv straight into your pandas DataFrame. Here we can set `parse_dates` with the columns you want as dates and then use `dayfirst`. This is defaulted to `false` so the following should do what you want, assuming the dates are in the first column.

```
df = pd.read_csv('myfile.csv', parse_dates=[0], dayfirst=True)
```

If the dates column is not the first row, just change the `0` to the column number.

Comment: This does not do anything, I mean, nothing changes in the output I still get a pandas dataframe with 261,332 rows

Comment: You are a genius!

Comment: Thank you, but I am certainly not. Wes McKinney and the wider pandas dev team are :)

Comment: Solid explanation (hence the vote-up on answer), but on top of that, excellent name @LittleBobbyTables! A much needed laugh in these strange and uncertain times

Answer (score 0):

The format of dates that you have included in your question don't seem to match your strftime filter. Take a look at [this](http://strftime.org/) to fix your string parameter.
It looks to me that it should be something in the lines of:

```
'%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S'
```

Comment: I did try your suggestion, but I still get a pandas dataframe with 261,332 rows. The strftime filter in my code is to remove the 'seconds' from the index, thats all.